# Test a form which used veevalidate on that form

Tags: vue.js, mocha.js, chai, vee-validate

i using vee-validate version 3.0.11 for validate my form like below

```html
           <validation-observer v-slot="{ invalid }" slim>

              <validation-provider rules="required" v-slot="{ errors, dirty, invalid}" slim>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="sr-only" for="txtUsername"></label>
                  <input
                    autocomplete="off"
                    id="txtUsername"
                    name="username"
                    type="text"
                    class="form-control txtUsername"
                    placeholder="Email or Username"
                    v-model="username"
                    v-bind:class="{ 'is-invalid': invalid && dirty,'is-valid': !invalid }" />


                </div>
              </validation-provider>
              <validation-provider rules="required" v-slot="{ errors, dirty, invalid}" slim>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="sr-only" for="txtPassword"></label>
                  <input
                    id="txtPassword"
                    name="password"
                    type="password"
                    class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Password"
                    v-model="password"
                    v-bind:class="{ 'is-invalid': invalid && dirty,'is-valid': !invalid }" />

                </div>
              </validation-provider>

              <div >
                <button
                  type="button"
                  name="login"
                  class="btn btn-primary"
                  v-on:click="doLogin()"
                  :disabled="invalid">
                  Login
                </button>
              </div>
            </validation-observer>
```

and i wrote some test with chai and mocha 
in my test i need to find the button 
but when i using find method for find button all html tag between `validation-observer` tag is not loaded in my wrapper. 
my test code is:

```js
// i change it to shallowMount to mount but problem is exist, 
// mount does not render any thing between validation-observer tag
const wrapper = mount(LoginView, { sync: false });

describe('Login.vue', () => {
    it('some text, () => {
        console.log(wrapper.html());
        // my log include all of tag except tags between the validation-observer tag
    });
});
```

can some one tell me how i can find my button by using warraper.find(), please?

Comment: Probably because you are using `shallowMount` instead of `mount`, you should always use `mount` as it gives a more reliable output at the cost of the tests running time.

Comment: @logaretm i try `mount` too but still it not render the html between of `validation observer` tag

Comment: try to use `flush-promises` right after you mount since rendering is async, you can check the vee-validate tests on GitHub.

Comment: I have had a similar problem. Using mount instead of shallowMount solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to shallow mount a component that needs to be mounted in order to [render its children](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/blob/master/src/components/Provider.ts#L198). If you want to ignore `ValidationProvider` all together you can provide a fake one as shown below.

> ContactForm.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <ValidationProvider rules="required" name="input" v-slot="{ errors }">
      <p :style="{color: 'red'}">To be, or not to be</p>
      <input type="text" v-model="value">
      <span id="error">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
    </ValidationProvider>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ValidationProvider } from "vee-validate";

export default {
  name: "ContactForm",
  components: {
    ValidationProvider
  },
  data: () => ({
    value: ""
  })
};
</script>
```

> ContactForm.test.js

```js
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from "@vue/test-utils";
import ContactForm from "./ContactForm";
import FakeValidationProvider from "./FakeValidationProvider";

test("Test shallow mount renders what's inside validation provider", async () => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue();

  var wrapper = shallowMount(ContactForm, {
    stubs: {
      ValidationProvider: FakeValidationProvider
    },
    localVue
  });

  expect(wrapper.text()).toContain("To be, or not to be");
});
```

> FakeValidationProvider.vue

```js
<template>
  <div v-bind="{ ...$props, ...$attrs }">
    <slot :errors="errors"></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "FakeValidationProvider",
  data() {
    return {
      errors: []
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Feel free to extend the slot with any other parameters you need besides errors. If you want to make those parameters dynamic as well, check out [this article on rendering slots](https://alexjover.com/blog/test-vue-js-slots-in-jest/)